Pillow/Python defaulting to 72 DPI on a Retina display - looks terrible. How can I achieve a higher DPI?
I have an issue when displaying images using Pillow on my Retina display. I have a folder of images that are 150x150 pixels, and when I try to display them with a circular mask, they appear pixelated and low quality due to the default 72 DPI.  If I try using bigger images it simply occupies too much space on my screen and doesn't utilize its Retina display either.
What I want to achieve is to control the DPI or scale these images properly to match my Retina display (which has a higher DPI). Here's a snippet of the relevant code and a screenshot:
enter image description here

# Constants for general settings
WINDOW_MIN_WIDTH = 700
WINDOW_MIN_HEIGHT = 350
GRID_COLUMNS = 9  # Number of columns for the grid layout
IMAGE_DIAMETER = 132  # Diameter for the circular images
border_width = 4
DEFAULT_THEME = "blue"
APPEARANCE_MODE = "dark"
IMAGE_BRIGHTNESS = 0.5

#.... Omitted a bunch of code which is more about how to find the images using os pointless for this dpi issue

    def create_circular_image(self, image_path, diameter, border_width):
        """
        Create a circular image with a border and anti-aliasing for smoother edges.
        """
        try:
            # Load the image and ensure it's square
            img = Image.open(image_path)
            square_size = min(img.width, img.height)
            img = img.crop((0, 0, square_size, square_size))

            # Resize with high-quality resampling to reduce pixelation
            img = img.resize((diameter, diameter), Image.LANCZOS)

            # Apply a circular mask with anti-aliasing
            mask = Image.new("L", img.size, 0)
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
            draw.ellipse((0, 0, diameter, diameter), fill=255)
            img.putalpha(mask)

            # Determine the group (subdirectory) and border color
            group = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(image_path))
            ring_color = GROUP_COLORS.get(group, "white")  # Default to white if not found

            # Create a new border with anti-aliasing
            new_diameter = diameter + 2 * border_width
            bordered_img = Image.new("RGBA", (new_diameter, new_diameter), ring_color)
            border_mask = Image.new("L", (new_diameter, new_diameter), 0)
            border_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(border_mask)
            border_draw.ellipse((0, 0, new_diameter, new_diameter), fill=255, outline=0)

            # Calculate the position to center the circular image within the bordered frame
            img_pos = ((new_diameter - img.width) // 2, (new_diameter - img.height) // 2)

            # Apply the circular mask to ensure smooth edges
            bordered_img.paste(img, img_pos, mask)
            bordered_img.putalpha(border_mask)

            # Convert to CTkImage for high DPI support
            ctk_image = CTkImage(light_image=bordered_img, dark_image=bordered_img, size=(new_diameter, new_diameter))

            return ctk_image



#... Omitted more until I reference the actual creation for the buttons which calls that function

    def create_phenotype_controls(self, image_paths):
        """
        Create controls for images and sliders.
        """
        phenotype_names = self.extract_phenotypes_from_paths(image_paths)

        for idx, (image_path, phenotype_name) in enumerate(itertools.zip_longest(image_paths, phenotype_names)):
            frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.grid_frame)
            frame.grid(row=idx // GRID_COLUMNS, column=idx % GRID_COLUMNS, padx=2.5, pady=2.5)


            # Create circular image
            image = self.create_circular_image(image_path, IMAGE_DIAMETER, border_width)
            image_widget = ctk.CTkButton(frame, image=image, text="",command=lambda idx=idx: self.toggle_phenotype(idx),fg_color="gray12")  # Ensure no text
            image_widget.pack(padx=0,pady=0, fill="both")  # Fill the available space

            self.buttons.append(image_widget)  # Store the button reference

#... Omitted last bit of code here

I can't seem to find a way to properly adjust the DPI in Pillow to work with my Retina display and avoid the pixelation when applying circular masks. Is there a solution or workaround for achieving higher DPI rendering for images on a Retina display using Pillow?
Here's what I've tried so far:

Increasing Image Sizes: I upscaled the images and applied various resampling techniques like Image.LANCZOS to improve clarity, but it didn’t make much of a difference.
Manually Setting DPI: I adjusted the DPI settings when saving images using Pillow, but it still defaults to 72 DPI, resulting in pixelated, low-quality images on my Retina display.
Applying Circular Masks: I created circular masks with anti-aliasing to smooth out the edges, but they still come out looking rough and pixelated.
CustomTkinter: I tested CustomTkinter, which offers flexibility, and using a circle object worked better, but when using Pillow for images, I couldn't overcome the 72 DPI constraint.
Mac APIs (Quartz with pyobjc): I even explored macOS APIs like Quartz through the pyobjc package, hoping it would help me manage high-DPI rendering directly, but the images still didn't look right.

Despite all these attempts, I can't get images to display at the quality of my Mac M2 Retina display. It feels like Pillow just can't handle high-DPI settings properly. Is there a way around this limitation, or is there a better approach to displaying high-DPI images using Python on a Retina display?

For DPI issue, all you can do just set the DPI for tkinter, but it won't help.
IMO, you didn't  really create an anti-aliasing circle, and it cannot be done by simple Pillow methods.
Example Code
from math import sqrt
from io import BytesIO
from copy import deepcopy
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

def move_to_center():
    root.update()
    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    win_width = root.winfo_width()
    win_height = root.winfo_height()
    x, y = (screen_width - win_width) // 2, (screen_height - win_height) // 2
    root.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")

def circle(radius=10, color=(0, 0, 255)):
    r0 = radius
    r_square = r0**2
    x, y = 0, r0-1  # left-botton of point, measure right-top point
    r, g, b = color
    div = 4
    im = Image.new("RGBA", (2*r0, 2*r0), (0, 0, 0, 0))

    while y>=x:
        total = 0
        for dy in range(1, div+1):
            for dx in range(1, div+1):
                if r_square >= (x+dx/4)**2+(y+dy/4)**2:
                    total += 1
        a = int(255*total/div**2)
        c = (r, g, b, a)
        im.putpixel((r0+x,   r0+y),   c)
        im.putpixel((r0+y,   r0+x),   c)
        im.putpixel((r0+x,   r0-y-1), c)
        im.putpixel((r0+y,   r0-x-1), c)
        im.putpixel((r0-x-1, r0+y),   c)
        im.putpixel((r0-y-1, r0+x),   c)
        im.putpixel((r0-x-1, r0-y-1), c)
        im.putpixel((r0-y-1, r0-x-1), c)

        x += 1
        if (x+1)**2+y**2 >= r_square:
            y -= 1

    c = color + (255, )
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.ellipse((2, 2, 2*r0-3, 2*r0-3), fill=c, width=0)
    # fill color
    points = [(1, r0)]
    checked = []
    while points:
        temp = []
        for point in points:
            checked.append(point)
            r, g, b, a = im.getpixel(point)
            if (r, g, b) != color:
                im.putpixel(point, c)
                x0, y0 = point
                for dx, dy in ((-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)):
                    p = (x0+dx, y0+dy)
                    if p not in checked and p not in temp:
                        temp.append(p)
        points = deepcopy(temp)
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

root = tk.Tk()

radius = 150
font = ("Courier New", 16)
image1 = circle(radius, (0, 0, 255))

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(frame1, width=radius*2+10, height=radius*2+10, background='white')
canvas1.pack()
label1 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Anti-Aliasing Circle", font=font)
label1.pack()
canvas1.create_image(radius+5, radius+5, image=image1)

im = Image.new("RGBA", (radius*2, radius*2), (255, 255, 255, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.ellipse((0, 0, radius*2, radius*2), fill=(0, 0, 255, 255))
image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
canvas2 = tk.Canvas(frame2, width=radius*2+10, height=radius*2+10, background='white')
canvas2.pack()
label2 = tk.Label(frame2, text="Pillow Circle", font=font)
label2.pack()
canvas2.create_image(radius+5, radius+5, image=image2)

frame3 = tk.Frame(root)
frame3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
canvas3 = tk.Canvas(frame3, width=radius*2+10, height=radius*2+10, background='white')
canvas3.pack()
label3 = tk.Label(frame3, text="Tkinter Circle", font=font)
label3.pack()
canvas3.create_oval(5, 5, 2*radius+5, 2*radius+5, fill="#0000FF", outline="#0000FF")

move_to_center()
root.mainloop()



Thank you so much for the help. The antialiasing method worked amazingly well. Clearly I was going about it directly using the Pillow Circle method which was unoptimal.  Technically however, the Tkinter circle method is actually the best on my mac due to retina but becuase it requires some additional coding (since I need to set up a separate canvas I think), it appears anti aliasing gets the job some easiest.  I may reach out in the future if I run into another issue if that’s ok, regardless much appreciated!
